# Perl Parsing with XML::Simple and Adding Escape Characters

Tags: perl, escaping

I need to escape certain character values from the data returned in an xml parsing I am doing. The problem is I need to have some sort of check for ALL values in the xml parsing. For example, if I have the following:

```
<data>this is sample data"</data>
```

I need to be able to add an escape character in front of the double quote character value so that if the value is stored to $x, and I print $x, it will show:

```
this is sample data\"
```

Thanks.

Comment: I guess what I am asking is if there is some sort of flag I can set in the XML::Simple parsing that will automatically add an escape character to these values.

Comment: srowley - The transformation you mentioned is very off-piste for XML::Simple, and it's trivially simple with an 's///' operator, which suggests I should ask you this question: Why do you want to do this escaping?

Answer (score 3):

This has nothing to do with XML, parsing, or a combination thereof. You have a variable that contains

```
this is sample data"
```

You want to change that variable to contain

```
this is sample data\"
```

You can escape every non-word character using [`quotemeta`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/quotemeta.html)

```
my $s = 'this is sample data"';
my $escaped = quotemeta($s);
```

You can escape just certain characters (say `\` and `"`) using the substitution operator.

```
my $s = 'this is sample data"';
( my $escaped = $s ) =~ s/(?=[\\"])/\\/g;
```

Perl 5.14+:

```
my $s = 'this is sample data"';
my $escaped = $s =~ s/(?=[\\"])/\\/rg;
```

Answer (score 3):

From the `XML::Simple` perldoc:

> By default, "XMLout()" will translate the characters ’<’, ’>’, ’&’ and
>   ’"’ to `&lt;`, `&gt;`, `&amp;` and `&quot;` respectively.

If you want those characters to be properly escaped as valid XML when converting from a hashref to an XML string (i.e. before writing your XML back out to file) then you needn't change anything.

If you want to escape those characters in some other way when converting to an XML string, you should extend `XML::Simple` and override the `escape_value()` method (note that a backslash is not the proper way to escape those characters in XML).

If you want to escape the contents of the scalar values in the hashref produced by `XMLin()` for some other reason, then the other answers will do the job.

Answer (score 0):

`XML::Simple` will not escape characters for you, because within XML escaping is done with entities - for instance a double quote is represented as `&quot;`.

The Perl built-in function `quotemeta` may be what you want. It escapes everything that isn't alphanumeric or an underscore.

```
print quotemeta q/this is sample data"/;
```

**OUTPUT**

```
this\ is\ sample\ data\"
```